# content in options in asp.net dropdown list getting cut/overlapping

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

[as you can see in the image attached, the text in the dropdown list gets cut/ is overlapping due to which complete text is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1rgU.png)

I have a dropdown list in aspx page which i am binding via db and i have not given any fixed height to the dropdownlist control as seen below

Happening on a display with resolution 1680*1050. works well with resolution of 1366*768. have searched a lot on web but no solution as such. plz help !

this is markup for this drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLossTypeTime" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    Width="75%" style="height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;overflow-y:auto"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: this is my dropdown list tag <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLossTypeTime" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" Width="75%" style="height: auto !important;overflow: visible !important;overflow-y:auto"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: try to set line height thru css, something like `select { line-height: 110% }` or inline `<asp:DropDownList style="line-height:110%" .../>`

Comment: thanks for the relply nino but i have already tried applying line-height, max-height, overflow etc

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: visible
```

to `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: have tried both, overflow:visible and also overflow : auto, but it didn't work.